# Restangular put requests.. how and why?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

If I have a resource, e.g.

```
var resource = Restangular.all('things');
```

and I have json object that I want to post to the API

```
jsonObj = {
  someVar: "x",
  anotherVar: "y"
}
```

I can simply do

```
resource.post(jsonObj).then( ...etc... )
```

Now if I update the model on the clientside and want to save the changes, why can I not do:

```
resource.put(thingId, updatedJsonObj)
```

I'm having trouble getting my head around the demos around on the internet, as they all appear to need to do a get request before they can do a put? Which seems odd. It's worth mentioning that I am using Restangular in a SERVICE, not in a controller or directive. My service has a variable `allMyThings` which is the result of `resource.getList()` and I use that in various places in the application

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you take one item in the collection returned by `getList()`, you can use `.save()` on it, and it will call `PUT` method.

```
angular.module('demo').controller('DemoCtrl', function (myList) {

  // myList is populated by Restangular.all('...').getList();

  var item = myList[0];

  item.name = 'foo';

  item.save()                // this one did a PUT :)
    .then(function (res) {
       // ...
    });

});
```

[See it in the docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

**NOTE :**

Restangular will use the `id` property as id for `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc. calls.
If you want to change that behaviour, use this in module config :

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
  id: "_id"
});
```

Comment: How can I use the id to get the specific record I want? For example rather than `myList[0]` I wanted `myList[record where id is 28]`

Comment: It might help if I clarify my exact goals, I have an angular service that I use to expose two lists, `listOfAllThings` and `listOfSelectedThings` the user selects things from the `listOfAllThings` and they get pushed into the selected list. While in the selected list, the models for these things can be edited and have attributes changed, then I want to PUT those changes back to the db.

Comment: and I'd like the PUT to return a promise so I can handle success/fail